# Array gives junk values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The program should print minimum and maximum but i get some error and
junk values :/

This is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
void minMax(int arr[], int size, int* max, int* min);

int main()
{
    int maximum, minimum, i;
    int arr[5];

    printf("Please enter 5 numbers: ");

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++);
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    minMax(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]), &maximum, &minimum);
    printf("Max is: %d \nMin is: %d", maximum, minimum);

    return(0);
}

void minMax(int arr[], int size, int* max, int* min)
{
    int i;
    *max = *min = arr[0];

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (*max < arr[i])
            *max = arr[i];
        if (*min > arr[i])
            *min = arr[i];
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And this is what I get:
[image]

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++);` remove last `;`

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf` as well

Comment: Don't post images. Site rules require to post as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in C it is legal to say `for(i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++);`

it means the same thing as

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
{}
```

it is also legal to use { and } to put snippet of code in its own block. that is why you have no compile error but are not getting the output you need

Comment: The braces **are** the block.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that..

Comment: @Olaf can you please elaborate?

Comment: `;` is a _null statement_, the braces make the block: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8p3 and http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.2 (plus 6.8.2p2). It is just standard C syntax one should learn with the very first lessons.

Comment: and how does this contradict what I said